# format disk with APFS, the new apple file system?

Tags: disk-utility, hdiutil

Has anyone managed to format an actual real disk with the new apple filesystem APFS in Mac OS Sierra ?

the documentation explains how to make a disk image with APFS:

```
hdiutil create -fs APFS -size 1GB foo.sparseimage
```

However, when trying to restore this image to a real disk with either 'Disk Utility' (GUI) or 'asr' (CLI), I get a "`is not valid for restoring`" error.

I've created several different disk images in different formats (`-format` flag to `hdiutil`) in the hopes of creating a disk image that could be used for restoring to a real disk, but the error always stayed the same.

Did anyone managed to get APFS on a real disk?

Comment: What is the error number of the error (250-261)?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 1 GPT APFS TEST R

diskutil list
```

should give:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:           GUID_partition_scheme                    *480.1 GB   disk2
   1:                         EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                      Apple_APFS                     479.9 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk2s2s1 (external, virtual):

   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                APFS Volume TEST                   +24.6 KB    disk2s2s1
```

Comment: Only issue is that Apple is not making it bootable until sometime in 2017. "A Developer Preview of Apple File System is available in macOS Sierra. Apple plans to release Apple File System as a bootable file system in 2017."